# How can I make a map from 2 lists?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 `List<String>`s, the first one represents a list of all items, and the second represents selected items.

So I would get a `Map<String, Boolean>`, from those lists, whose keys are all list1's items, and value is `list2.contains(itemOfList1)` (`true` or `false`).

```
Map<String, Boolean> mapOfDataListTest = itemList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, value -> true));
```

Comment: A side note: Unless you explicitly want to assign a certain semantics to `null` (or you explicitly need a `Map` for some downstream method), a `Map<T, Boolean>` hardly ever makes sense: It is structurally equivalent to a `Set<T>` in that checking `Boolean.TRUE.equals(map.get(t))` is the same as `set.contains(t)`.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `value -> true` with a lambda `item -> list2.contains(item)` or a method reference `list2::contains`

```
itemList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), list2::contains));
```

and read [@michalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4956907/michalk)'s comment.

Comment: Isn't better use `Set` instead of `List`?

Comment: It's not a question, and I assume the volume of data isn't large, so it won't make a significant difference. It's a good point, though.

Comment: Very nice solution however I agree with HadiJ. It should be noted that `List::contains` is O(N) and if we substituted `list2` with `Set` we could achieve better performance since `Set::contains` is (usually) O(1). However it still depends on sizes of those two lists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: for better performance use `Set`.

```
Set<String> selected  = new HashSet<>(list2);

Map<String, Boolean> mapOfDataListTest = itemList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, value ->selected.contains(value) ));
```